# How to read and write files to my cache?

Tags: android, caching

I want to save some cache data for my appliaction. I used to do this by saving the data in the external storage and this worked fine. But I want my device to show my cache size in the app settings but It doesn´t. I guess this is because I save the data in external storage. What I want is that my data still exists aufter closing the app or even swichen off my device. Now I tried to save my files in the internal storage but I have troubles reading the files + the cache size is still wrong in settings. Can anyone give me the methodes do write and read strings into files in the applications cache please?

Comment: 'but I have troubles reading the files'. Which troubles? Reading and writing files use the same methods for internal and external memory. So what is your problem exactly? Also tell what you consider to be 'the application path'. Full path please.

Answer (score 13):

I think everything is clearly explained [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)... :)

if you have juste simple data, you can use SharedPreferences like this for example :

```
public static void writeString(Context context, final String KEY, String property) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES_KEY, context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString(KEY, property);
    editor.commit();
}

public static String readString(Context context, final String KEY) {
    return context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES_KEY, context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(KEY, null);
}
```

in order to use the cache, you have to use the method

```
File file = new File(context.getCacheDir(), filename);
```

which return a File object you can write and read on.

Use this to write :

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bw.write(fcontent);
bw.close();
```

Be aware that Android may delete this file if the system lack space, so don't use this to store too much data. ( > 1MB)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Yes sorry, didn't think of this case