# Java - From SVG to PNG programmatically

Tags: java, android, svg, png, batik

I'm creating a game with LibGDX library (from badlogicgames) and I ran into some doubts about my sprites.

In order to support different screen sizes, we usually create like 4 maybe 6 images with different sizes. I was wondering if using a vector image like.SVG files may be useful.

Would it be smart to get programmatically an SVG file, get screen dimensions and then create an appropriate PNG file taking the screen size into account?

If the only problem is performance, is the difference too significantly? Maybe creating all the PNG images at the beginning of the app would take 3 or 4 seconds but it would be better for forward graphics.

I've heard about **batik** for achieving this, has anybody tried this?

Has anybody a bit of experience with this stuff and can help me?

Comment: Android support library now supports vector images. The library caches the images, so they are only converted once. The docs do state that due to memory issues, it should only be used for relative small images.

Comment: @lionscribe The Android Support Library does not support SVG files. It supports VectorDrawables, which are not the same.  A subset of SVG files can be converted to VectorDrawable files.

Comment: Correct. The most important point I wanted is the noted memory issue. Full size images will hog your memory. A simple idea would be, that you save the image files on the first run to cache file, so you will usually not have to create them again, nor have large images in memory.

Comment: Do you have a tutorial for saving PNG files in the app's cache?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33432322/2661303

Answer (score 1):

Batik would be appropriate for a general Java application.  However I don't believe it supports Android because it uses the standard Java2D methods which Android doesn't have.

However there are libraries for Android that allow you to render SVG files:

- [AndroidSVG](https://github.com/BigBadaboom/androidsvg) *Supports most SVG features*
- [svg-android](https://github.com/pents90/svg-android) *Supports a limited set of SVG features*

*Disclaimer: I am the author of AndroidSVG*

Comment: So I put the SVG in my assets folder, I convert them in PNG files with AndroidSVG and then I save them in the game's cache. Well, in order to finish the debate, do you have a tutorial for saving PNG files in the cache? Thanks a lot !

Comment: There is an example of how to create a Bitmap from an SVG on the [AndroidSVG web site](http://bigbadaboom.github.io/androidsvg/). The only step left for you to do is to save in PNG format.

Comment: How do I implement AndroidSVG from a libGDX project in Android Studio ?

Comment: You should just be able to import it as you would any other library JAR.