# How to save different types of data(string name , int color, Drawable icon) in internal storage?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, internal-storage

I want to save multiple data in internal storage Android, I want to store different names with details that contain images, names, colors of the item list, and as I said I want to save all of this information. my question is how can I save these data.

this is my  Adaptor class.

```
    public class MyAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<DataModel> {
    List<DataModel> dataModels;
    int layoutRes;
    EditText editText;
    TextView textView;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;




    public MyAdaptor(Context context, int resource , List<DataModel> dataModels) {
        super( context, resource,dataModels );

        this.dataModels = dataModels;
        this.layoutRes = resource;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from( context );

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dataModels.size();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView==null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate( layoutRes,parent,false);

        }
        textView = convertView.findViewById( R.id.txt );
        ImageView imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon  );
        LinearLayout linearLayout = convertView.findViewById( R.id.linearL );
        ImageButton imageButton = convertView.findViewById( R.id.add );
        ImageButton imageButton1Edit = convertView.findViewById( R.id.edit );
        ImageButton imageButton1Remove = convertView.findViewById(R.id.remove  );

        textView.setText( dataModels.get( position ).getTxt() );
        linearLayout.setBackgroundColor( dataModels.get( position ).getColor() );
        imageView.setBackground( dataModels.get( position ).getIcon());


        return convertView;

    }
}
```

this is my  DataModel class.

```
    public class DataModel {
    int color;
    String txt;
    Drawable icon;

    public DataModel(int color, String txt, Drawable icon) {
        this.color = color;
        this.txt = txt;
        this.icon = icon;
    }


    public int getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getTxt() {
        return txt;
    }

    public void setTxt(String txt) {
        this.txt = txt;
    }

    public Drawable getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(Drawable icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }
}
```

this is my  MainActivity.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<DataModel> dataModelArrayList;
    ListView listView;
    MyAdaptor myAdaptor;
    EditText editText;
    View view;
    ImageView imageView;
    String str ;
    Drawable ii;
    int color;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main );
        dataModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        myAdaptor = new MyAdaptor( MainActivity.this,R.layout.listview_item , dataModelArrayList );
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editetxt );
        view = findViewById(R.id.view );
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.image );


        ii = imageView.getDrawable();

        ColorDrawable colorDrawable = (ColorDrawable) view.getBackground();
        color = colorDrawable.getColor();
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.save);
        button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                str = editText.getText().toString();
                DataModel da =new DataModel( color,str,ii );             
                dataModelArrayList.add(da);
                myAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
               

            }
        } );

        listView.setAdapter( myAdaptor );

    }
}
```

Comment: If your data is only text then try converting it to json and save it in sharedpreferences. for images you can save them in cache directory of your app data folder.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33431314/how-to-read-and-write-files-to-my-cache

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want to use internal storage to save them.